# How to stop caching of images in an email?

Tags: c#, email, caching, amazon-ses

I am sending an email using c# and Amazon SES. The email consists of several images. when I open that email for the first time on my client it loads all images from the host but when i open it for the second time it seems all the images are pre-loaded and I don't want this behavior. I know this is because of caching but how can I force not to cache those images and reloads every time from the hosted server.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is an unusual request as normally caching is the correct behaviour. Please can you explain *why* you don't want caching, as there may be a more appropriate solution might be dependent on your specific use case.

Comment: The images in the email would change very frequently that's why i want to load images every time.

Comment: can i put this <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE"> in email message ?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense - people will generally only open an email once. Are you expecting people to re-open your email on a regular basis? That would be an unusual expectation.

Comment: The email is not for general public. It is for specific people and they would be asked to open that email more than once? Is there any solution ?

Comment: I doubt there is a robust solution for this, but the critical thing will be the specific email client that your users use, as any solution will likely be client-specific. Please can you edit your question to include that information, and maybe someone else can help you. However, I would suggest that this information would be better presented in a web-page or similar, where you have multiple robust techniques to ensure the information presented is up-to-date. Perhaps the email could have a link to such a web-page?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a web.config file in your email images directory. This should indicate to the email client (when requesting images) that these images being served are not to be cached (provided said email client implements the HTTP procotol correctly)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
  <location>
   <system.web>
    <authorization>
     <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
    </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <staticContent>
     <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
    </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
  </location>
 </configuration>
```